# Virtual Hosting on Centos 7

Tags: centos, virtualhost, apache-2.4, centos7

I'm trying to set up Virtual Hosting on my server which is running Cent OS 7. I have done the following but it is not working:

1. created a file called called vhost.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d
2. Add the following content to the file vhost.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/domain_name
      ServerName www.domainname.com
      ErrorLog /var/www/domain_name/domain_name.log
      CustomLog logs/virtual.host-access_log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. On my DNS Manager, in the A record for wwww, I have added the ip address of my server

Is there anyplace where I have wronged in the steps above?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: when I am putting two servers, say domain1 & domain2, and i'm creating two directories, all traffic are routing to domain1 instead

Comment: Did you reload/restart Apache?